# how to implement accordion per user using netzke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, accordion, netzke

Here is the requirement:

In a border layout UI, a user(staff) grid is at the west, while the accordion at the center will show the selected user's several collections(say, awards, etc) in each panel when one staff is selected.

The code:

```
class StaffsAndAwards < Netzke::Base
  # Remember regions collapse state and size
  include Netzke::Basepack::ItemPersistence

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.items = [
      { netzke_component: :staffs, region: :west, width: 300, split: true },
      { netzke_component: :accordion, region: :center }
    ]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.layout = :border
    c.border = false

    # Overriding initComponent
    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function(){
        // calling superclass's initComponent
        this.callParent();

        // setting the 'rowclick' event
        var view = this.getComponent('staffs').getView();
        view.on('itemclick', function(view, record){
          this.selectStaff({staff_id: record.get('id')});
          this.getComponent('awards').getStore().load();
        }, this);
      }
    JS
  end

  endpoint :select_staff do |params, this|
    component_session[:selected_staff_id] = params[:staff_id]
  end

  component :staffs do |c|
    c.klass = Netzke::Basepack::Grid
    c.model = "Staff"
    c.region = :west
  end

  component :awards do |c|
    c.kclass = Netzke::Basepack::Grid
    c.model = 'Award'
    c.data_store = {auto_load: false}
    c.scope = {:staff_id => component_session[:selected_staff_id]}
    c.strong_default_attrs = {:staff_id => component_session[:selected_staff_id]}
  end

  component :accordion do |c|
    c.klass = Netzke::Basepack::Accordion
    c.region = :center
    c.prevent_header = true
    c.items = [ { :title => "A Panel" }, :awards ]    # The error may occur here. :awards cannot be found. 
  end

end
```

The error is "NameError (uninitialized constant Awards)". Seems :awards component can not be found, even though it's already defined in the above.

Can one component be embedded in another one? 
Or how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a pretty common mistake here, declaring the :awards component as a child of StaffsAndAwards, while it should be a child of the Accordion.

It's easy to fix. Declare your accordion component separately (say, we name it AwardsAndStuff), move the :awards declaration over to it, then refer to it in StaffAndAwards:

```
component :accordion do |c|
  # if you call the component :awards_and_stuff instead of :accordion, next line is not needed
  c.klass = AwardsAndStuff

  # important - pass the staff_id
  c.staff_id = component_session[:selected_staff_id]

  c.region = :center
  c.prevent_header = true
end
```

Inside AwardsAndStuff you can access staff_id as `config.staff_id`, and pass it to the :awards component:

```
component :awards do |c|
  c.kclass = Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  c.model = 'Award'
  c.data_store = {auto_load: false}
  c.scope = {:staff_id => config.staff_id}
  c.strong_default_attrs = {:staff_id => config.staff_id}
end
```

This way you'll also be able to test AwardsAndStuff standalone.

Comment: Thank you, almost done. The :awards component does not get refreshed automatically after one staff is clicked. Only when the refresh button of :awards component is clicked, the data is displayed. How to fix this?

Comment: This can be application specific. Make this responsibility of the Accordion component, which should implement a "refresh" method or something: it should "decide" whether to refresh only the current pane, or all panes at once. The latter is probably the simplest: cycle through its panes, and call getStore().reload() on each.

Comment: Only the first panel can reload its data, the others can not. I cloned yanit app and had added a new feature(menu item): "Users and Issues", implemented just in the same way as the above and the problems are same also.  The repo: https://github.com/douyw/yanit.git

Comment: Using `Netzke::Basepack::Accordion` complicates things by introducing dynamic loading of panes. Try inherit from `Netzke::Base` instead, and set `layout` to `:accordion`. This way all the panes will be loaded eagerly - and thus `item.getStore().reload();` should start working. For more details: http://writelesscode.com/blog/2012/12/17/nesting-netzke-components/